# Can't get the tags to render in a dropdown with array.map in a method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I can't seem to get this code snippet working for my dropdown menu, it's meant to make a dropdown with all the "kushTypes"

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

class Boxes extends Component {
    state = {
        drugTypes: ["Weed", "Coke", "Meth"],
        kushTypes: ["OG Kush", "Purple haze", "Banana Kush"],
        drugs: {
            weed: "https://i.imgur.com/EG5SUSF.png",
            coke: "https://i.imgur.com/BRPbClP.jpg"
        }

    }
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                { this.renderWeedCard() }           
            </div>
         );
    }

    renderWeedCard() {
        return (
            <div className="card" style={{ width: '400px' }}>
                    <div className="card-body text-center">
                        <h4 className="card-title">{this.state.drugTypes[0]}</h4>
                        <p className="card-text">Denna kushen är det bästa du kan hitta i hela city, köper du detta kommer alla vilja köpa av dig, så hmu idag! :D</p>
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Vad vill du beställa
                            </button>
                            <div className="dropdown-menu">
                                {this.renderTags}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        ) 
    }

    renderTags = () => {
        return this.state.kushTypes.map(kush => <a key={kush} className="dropdown-item">{kush}</a>)
    }
}
export default Boxes;
```

If I wasn't clear before, the what I'm trying to do is render all the string from the "kushTypes" array to the a element in the dropdown menu

Comment: What is it doing now?

Comment: @Ashley It's not event showing

Comment: More details would make it easier to solve the problem - *what* isn't showing? The entire page? The "card" div? The "dropdown" div? Just the contents of "dropdown-menu" div? Do you have a screenshot? Do you have somewhere we can access a working example?

Comment: The dropdown "div" isn't showing on the button click, I click the button and nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually call this.renderTags

```
<div className="dropdown-menu">
    {this.renderTags}
</div>
```

Should be

```
 <div className="dropdown-menu">
     {this.renderTags()}
</div>
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wood-0tn16?file=/src/App.js) with the dropdown values showing.
As you can see the values show by default and the button does nothing.
I believe this is due to you missing Popper.js see these [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/).

Also I would suggest you take a look at react-bootstrap [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/). (I started an example in the above sandbox).

Comment: @Skeexs What do mean it's not working are you still not seeing the dropdown values at all?

Comment: Not seeing the dropdowns at all

Comment: Ok I'm seeing the dropdown values. I'll put together a sandbox when I have some time later today

Comment: @Skeexs I updated my answer with a link to a sandbox